# Conected components using opencv dilate, setting a starting point

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, connected-components, mathematical-morphology

I need to find connected components using opencv-python, `cv2.dilate()`

The problem is, can I set the starting point of connected components?

When I use `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats()`, there was a return `labels`,
so I could masked only I needed such as

```
seed_label = labels[seed_point[1], seed_point[0]]
component_mask = np.where(labels == seed_label, 255, 0).astype(np.uint8)
```

But when I use `cv2.dilate()`, it looks like there is no way to set a starting point.

Sorry for bad English.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: there is no starting point for CC labeling because it doesn't matter to CC labeling. there is no starting point to dilation because that too doesn't matter to dilation. -- take a step back, explain why you're doing all this. [edit] your question. present data.

Comment: How do you plant to implement connected component analysis using dilate? How would that work? I don’t see it.

Comment: You can, very inefficiently, implement a flooding operation using the dilation, maybe this is what you’re after?

Comment: perhaps OP requires _joining_ of CCs that are close enough. just guessing. needs moar detail.